# How to get WiFi-Signal Strength with Unity engine and C# on Android?

Tags: c#, android, android-wifi, unity-game-engine

I need the WiFi strength of nearly access points to triangulate the position of the Android device user and show him the part of the building, he is located at the moment. It's for a location based game for new students at my university. There are easy ways with Java or Xamarin and C#, but i couldn't find a way to solve the problem using the Unity engine and C#. It there a way to get it?

I have a complete Android solution in Java from a fellow student and i tried to use AndroidJavaObjects to use that in my program, but without success. It seems to be too complex for that. Are there maybe other ways to use that Java Android code in Unity?

Thanks in advance for the help.